# Spurious ValueError using learning_curve on sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel='rbf') classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am getting weird ValueError when using learning_curve on svm.SVC(kernel='rbf') classifier.

I am using:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import cross_validation, datasets, preprocessing
clf=svm.SVC(kernel='rbf')
cv=cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=10)
for enum, (train, test) in enumerate(cv):
      print("Fold {0}, classes in train {1}, \t classes in test {2}".format(enum, set(y[train]), set(y[test])))
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
    clf, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
```

I can see, there are both classes in train and test sets.

```
Fold 0, classes in train set([0, 1]),    classes in test set([0, 1])
Fold 1, classes in train set([0, 1]),    classes in test set([0, 1])
Fold 2, classes in train set([0, 1]),    classes in test set([0, 1])
Fold 3, classes in train set([0, 1]),    classes in test set([0, 1])
Fold 4, classes in train set([0, 1]),    classes in test set([0, 1])
Fold 5, classes in train set([0, 1]),    classes in test set([0, 1])
Fold 6, classes in train set([0, 1]),    classes in test set([0, 1])
Fold 7, classes in train set([0, 1]),    classes in test set([0, 1])
Fold 8, classes in train set([0, 1]),    classes in test set([0, 1])
Fold 9, classes in train set([0, 1]),    classes in test set([0, 1])
```

But then I get following error:

```
ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1
```

Could somebody please help in finding a workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: Please include the full traceback when you report an error message.

Answer (score 1):

This looks likely to be caused by the `learning_curve` which retrains the model on different sized subsamples of your data; by default the sample sizes are `train_sizes=array([ 0.1, 0.33, 0.55, 0.78, 1. ])`, depending on your data you may be able address the issue by leaving out the smaller fractions, for example by setting `train_sizes=array([0.55, 0.78, 1. ])`, you also should consider reducing the number of folds in your cross-validation.

Comment: Please see the code above again. I am checking set of values in both training and test sets for every fold. And output shows that in every fold, both train and test sets have both classes.